# How to compute the Power Spectral Density of an EEG signal

Tags: signal-processing

I have an EEG signal of length N on a given channel (FP1).

I would like to compute the power spectral density of the signal. More specifically, once the PSD is computed, I would like to sum the values of the PSD in a given band, say alpha band (e.g. 8Hz-13Hz).

So I know that the PSD is given by:

$$PSD=\frac{F_t F^*_t}{N}$$

where * denotes the conjugate and $F_t$ is the Fourier transform...

And then energy at a given band is given by:

$$\sum_{freq=8}^{13} PSD_freq$$

I am however not sure how to implement these equations in *Mathematica*.

Comment: The discrete Fourier transform is given by `Fourier`. You might also look at `Periodogram` and `PowerSpectralDensity`. You'll probably need to supply some example data (or a code snippet to generate fake data) to get a detailed answer.